# help with groovy GPATH

Tags: xml, xpath, groovy

I need to parse an googleReverseGeocoding XML response. The following code is a response sample.

```
<GeocodeResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<result>...</result>
<result>
  <type>sublocality</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>Oeiras, Portugal</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
    <long_name>Oeiras</long_name>
    <short_name>Oeiras</short_name>
    <type>sublocality</type>
    <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
    <long_name>Lisboa</long_name>
    <short_name>Lisboa</short_name>
    <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
    <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
<result>...</result>
<result>...</result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

I need to find the "long_name" tag with the value "Lisboa", which appears when the type tag is administrative_area_level_1.
I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
result.city = geocodeResponse.result.find{it.address_component.type == "administrative_area_level_1"}.address_component.find{it.type == "administrative_area_level_1"}.long_name as String
```

A little help would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
records = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
records.result.address_component.find { address ->
    address.type.any { type -> 
        type == 'administrative_area_level_1'
    }
}.long_name
```

Comment: What does the `.any` signify here? I can see `type` is an XML node, but what is `any` doing? just like iterating over children? Thanks much I realize this is from a decade ago.